# Get form textbox values as array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following form

```
<div ng-controller="Formctrl">
<form ng-submit="getNames(pd)">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
        <section class="col col-4" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:5">
        <label class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Names" ng-model="pd.names[$index]" >
        </label>
        </section>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Basically i want to bind the names in an array form submission. But i am getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

Here is my Controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('FormCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope){
        $scope.pd = {};
        $scope.getNames = function() { console.log($scope.pd); };

    });
```

I need the output something like below. How do i achieve it??

```
{
    names: [
        'Name 1',
        'Name 2',
        'Name 3',
        'Name 4',
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey You just try to reach an undefined element just define names in controller...

```
$scope.pd = {names : []};
```

here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/4FGcevAdloRGu7Uxc5Et)...

Comment: Oh it works! Thanks, but when i erase the submited value from textbox a null value is still left. cant i remove/ reset the names??

Comment: you can check validation of form if it is ok for you?

Comment: sorry dint get what you saying

Comment: @VishwaKumar you can watch and remove element from your array but I don't think it is a best solution, I wonder what you want to get when form is submitted we can focus that for another solution...]

Comment: Well , we have to make a check if the array value was present or no in a loop on the server side..wanted to just avoid that step